# Are the restrictions on native API gone for WinUI 3 vs UWP?

Tags: uwp, pinvoke, winui-3

For UWP I always used [this helpful page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/win32-and-com/win32-and-com-for-uwp-apps) to reference the things I can and cannot use.  Note that APIs outside of this list actually do function on desktop, but they are rejected from the store for failing validation (presumably because other platforms like phone will not have them).  I cannot seem to find a WinUI 3 specific version of the Windows App Certification Kit for testing this, and I am wondering if the same restrictions apply given that WinUI 3 is back to being desktop only.  Does anyone have a source on this?  When we released the first UWP package our users informed us that their apps were rejected from the store because of illegal API usage and I want to avoid going through that a second time for WinUI 3 / MAUI.

NOTE: Our package is an SDK that users consume in their apps, so we don't distribute applications, but just a library.

Comment: You might find some info in the GitHub repo, something like [this](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/3780), but for the moment, that's all I guess.

Comment: I think the rule is the same for the MSIX packages. I'll confirm this with the store team. If I got response, I would post it as answer.

Comment: One can now publish a "traditional desktop app" in the store https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-store/desktop-apps but details of submission (how it is packaged, etc) are important and policies change regularly https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/publish/store-policies-change-history the best is to check by yourself with your package https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/intelligence/developer-resources https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/filesubmission/

Comment: @SimonMourier I appreciate all the links.  This seems to be dealing with Microsoft Defender.  Do you mean to say that this is the new standard by which store apps are judged?  With UWP the WACK tool would immediately flag any applications using non whitelisted native API (Win32) calls.  This is what I am wondering about with the new WinUI 3 based system.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT Perhaps you could also ask if the WACK tool is still the source of truth?

Comment: I got the response from the store team. They think this should be a tech issue which should open a paid supported ticket. The best way I think is to create a test WinUI3 application which uses some win32 APIs and upload the winui3 app to the store.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT I think it is a docs issue.  UWP clearly laid out the requirements but WinUI 3 is shrouded in mystery as far as I can tell.